generate file_context linux based on folder and contains subfolders
I have the following method and I need it to read a directory containing 3 or more subdirectories and generate a selinux context txt file separated by the name of each folder:
[bash]
#!/bin/bash
dirprev=$PWD
extracted_dir=$1
file_context=$2
partition=${extracted_dir##*/}
IFS=$'\n'

echo "Checking fs config..."
echo ""

cd $extracted_dir
for i in $(find .); do
   j=${i:2}
   if [[ ! $(grep -rF "$partition/$j" $file_context) ]]; then
      test -f $extracted_dir/$j
      if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
         if [[ $(echo /$j | grep "/bin/") ]]; then
            echo $partition/$j 0 2000 0755 >> $file_context
         else
            echo $partition/$j 0 0 0644 >> $file_context
         fi
      else
         echo $partition/$j 0 0 0755 >> $file_context
      fi
   fi
done
cd $dirprev

eg:
folders
myfolder
 ....product_a -> product_a_file_context with all files builtin
 ....system_a -> system_a_file_context with all files builtin
 ....system_ext_a system_ext_a_file_context with all files builtin

each context file must only contain files from its directory
For files or folders that have a dot in the name, it needs to be generated as follows
files structure:
**original path: ./product_a/app/com.google.medatada
product_a_file_context: /product_a/app/com.\google.\metadata**

and saved in the corresponding text file of each folder

can you add the [bash] tag? This will highlight all your code

Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.
